# find string beetwen two element

Tags: php, string, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

i get page with file_get_content and i want extract all link in page any way to do this?
or can i use str with start an end phares to get target string like this :

```
$str=fdgdfbfbmnlmnjkl njnkhvnbn j<a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>
$link=str($str,"start","END")??????????
EX : $link=str($str,"http://www","com")=Res=>http://www.google.com or google?
```

or

```
$str=file_get_content("http://www.google.com");
    $link=str($str,"start","END")??????????
    EX : $link=str($str,"http://www","com")=Res=>http://www.google.com or google?
```

Comment: Please format your code to the *correct* syntax.

Comment: use a DOM parser, not regular expressions!

Comment: i want search in string and want code for return string beetwen two phares . no DO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem some time ago. This solution worked very well for me.

```
 $string = "Hello World, <a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a> ! Search also on <a href='http://www.bing.com'>Bing</a>";

 preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $string, $match);

 $matches = $match[0];

 foreach($matches as $var)
 {    
     print($var."<br>"); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use DOM methods to extract content from HTML - using regular expressions will [result in madness](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/6782):

```
<?php
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.google.com/');

    $a = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
    foreach ($a as $e) {
        echo $e->getAttribute("href") . "\n";
    }
?>
```